# Aluminium training rollers - seeking feedback on brands

Tags: rollers

we are looking to buy some new aluminium training rollers, but have no experience as to what brands deliver the best quality for the money.

In mind are the CycleOps and JetBlack brands, both of whom do aluminium rollers at around £150-170. Can anyone provide any positive or negative experiences with any of these brands, or know of better products in the same price range?

Many thanks,
Neil (UK)

Comment: Welcome to the site, Neil!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the [Tacx Antares](http://www.tacx.com/en/producten/rollenbanken/antares/index.dot). The rollers are heavy duty, coated aluminum, and are tapered to help self center your bike on the rollers. They are quiet and durable.

**Edit: Apparently the current Antares doesn't use aluminum rollers any more. Mine does, but it's 3 years old.**

In addition, they collapse to a length of 80cm, and have a bag available separately for traveling with them. Like Kreitler, replacement parts and service are readily available.

Pricing is in the range requested.

[image: Tacx Antares Rollers]

Comment: Hadn't noticed that these were aluminium too. Even the tacx website doesn't boast about it. Is the frame steel or plastic?

Comment: Steel. And the rollers are coated to keep them quiet. I haven't been asked specifically about aluminum rollers before. Are they considered better in a technical sense? This is the first set I've owned, and I bought the brand I was familiar with, since I also have the Fortius Multiplayer trainer. I like them, but I didn't look around much first.

Comment: I understand that the extra weight (hence inertia) of the metal roller means a smoother ride allowing for a smaller drum which provides more resistance. There is also a claimed benefit of not distorting in a warm environment. This may be marketing over substance, of course.

Comment: Well, as to that, I find the momentum of the Antares to be more than sufficient, and they are both smooth, and reasonably quiet. i live in Dubai, which means summer heat at 50c+, and no issues with distortion of the rollers, either.

Comment: Much obliged. That's been helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the update - where did you find out that the construction has changed?

Comment: I was in a shop downtown here yesterday, and the Antares they are displaying has nylon rollers. It still seems solid, but as I haven't ridden that version, and you were specifically looking at aluminum, I thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 0):

[Kreitler](http://www.kreitler.co.uk/) is widely considered to be the best. They are expensive, but if you read the reviews, you may be convinced!

Comment: I like the look of these rollers although I have no experience.  As somebody who doesn't (yet) use rollers, it seems it would be nice to start off with the front wheel removed and the forks clamped down.  Rollers always seem dangerous.  What if the bike jumps off the rollers?

Comment: Then you have a YouTube moment.

Comment: If the bike jumps off the rollers, you tip over. You DON'T go shooting forward through the wall or into the TV. You just tip over. It can hurt of course, but generally it's just embarrassing...

Comment: @Kibbee: Tacx has a fork support option for the Antares, so that you can get used to the rollers without too much risk. Don't know if it's needed, but it's there.

Comment: @Darren I was thinking more along the lines of cable skips off gets caught in rollers, or other freak thing causes rollers to stop rolling.  Then you just start going forward.

Comment: @Kibbee: I have been riding when the 'cable' snapped. The front roller slowly 'winds down' as it is not being driven. The rear two keep rolling via your wheel. You have plenty of time to stop safely before you lose balance. If things get tangled (HIGHLY unlikely in the first place,) I can't imagine it would come to a quick stop--the cables are actually rubber, and have some give to them. They'd like just get wrapped up or snap apart without causing a crash.

Comment: @Darren.  Good to know.  I've been thinking about getting training rollers for the winter.